# JQuery, Selectors - Child Elements and Contains Expressions

Tags: jquery, selector, contains

For Jquery and the Selector:
Is it possible to search for several strings in the contains sub-selector for nested child elements?

For Example:

```
<div>
    <span>foo</span>
    <span>bar</span>
</div>

// comma is usual OR operator.
$("div > span:contains(['foo'],['bar'])").css("text-decoration","underline");
```

Expected:
Both Elements get underlined.

If it's not implemented yet, can we get it implemented? ^-^

Comment: textdecoration to text-decoration

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can search for both or either many search terms containing a div or span or any other HTML element by using the following method

```
$('span:contains("foo"), span:contains("bar")').css("text-decoration", "underline") // either one OR two
$('span:contains("foo"):span:contains("bar")').css("text-decoration", "underline") //span, which contains both
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use .filter() like

```js
$("div > span").filter(":contains('foo'),:contains('bar')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: After looking at both solutions this is probably the more suitable one as it takes into account child elements. Thanks allot everyone. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-decartion` with '-' in synatax. You missed out i think

```
$("div span").each(function() {

   if($(this).text() == "foo" || $(this).text() == "bar"){

     $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
   }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgru0yfd/)